# Power analysis using Synopsys Design Compiler

Tags: power, asic, modelsim

I am trying to generate power report using Synopsys DC compiler.

At first I have generated VCD file using Modelsim simulator, which I have converted to SAIF file using "vcd2saif" command.
Then I proceeded to analyze the power through DC compiler.

However, I am getting an warning ***" There are 1166 objects not found during annotation"***, and the combinational switching power is showing zero for my design.

What can be the error?

I believe the internal signals in the generated SAIF file from the MODELSIM does not match with the internal signals of the synthesized netlist. Do I have to perform postsynthesis simulation, but then how to link the design library file with MODELSIM.

Kindly guide in this regard.

Comment: To update, I tried postsynthesis simulation using lib.v files corresponding to synthesis library. However, the size of vcd file now being generated is too large.

Comment: There are dedicated forums for every EDA tool. You should ask tool specific questions there for better answers.

Comment: @Mitu...Ok.Thank you for the advice. I will try that.